# Why are these 2 sectors different?

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs

i tried to read ntfs partition.
**main function**:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    BYTE sector[512];
    ReadSector(L"\\\\.\\E:", 0, sector);
    PrintBPB(ReadBPB(sector));

    BYTE sector2[512];
    ReadSector(L"\\\\.\\E:", 0, sector2);
    PrintBPB(ReadBPB(sector2));
    
    return 0;
}
```

**ReadSector function:**

```
int ReadSector(LPCWSTR  drive, long readPoint, BYTE sector[Sector_Size])
{
    int retCode = 0;
    DWORD bytesRead;
    HANDLE device = NULL;

    device = CreateFile(drive,    // Drive to open
        GENERIC_READ,           // Access mode
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,        // Share Mode
        NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
        OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
        0,                      // File attributes
        NULL);                  // Handle to template

    if (device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) // Open Error
    {
        printf("CreateFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    SetFilePointer(device, readPoint, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);//Set a Point to Read

    if (!ReadFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        printf("ReadFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!\n");
    }
    CloseHandle(device);
}
```

I think the way I copy those bytes into my BPB bpb is fine.

So what happend? Why they are different?
I can figure out that its relate to winapi, readfile, createfile but I still dont understand it :(

sorry for my bad english.

[image: here the result:]

Comment: The issue seems to be inside `PrintBPB`, that apparently switches from decimal to hexadecimal output (`512` is the same value as `0x200`). To verify whether the contents are the same, just call [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) on the raw binary data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is in the code we cannot see: `PrintBPB`. Apparently it switches to hexadecimal output (for the "Volume serial number") and then fails to switch back to decimal until later.

When the code calls `PrintBPB` a second time the output mode is still in hexadecimal format, and printing "Bytes per Sector" now displays `200` (`0x200` is the same value as `512`).

If you need to know whether two chunks of memory hold identical values, just [`memcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) them. This avoids introducing a bug in a transformation (such as console output).